# Create a permalink with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can I get a help about this :

I see on google webmaster tools broken links like this: 
test.php?t=test%20title

test.php page is removed and now I am using index.php instead of test.php

So I need to rewrite url again with htaccess. How can I do this?

http://www.domain.com/test.php?t=test%20title
link change to
http://www.domain.com/t/test-title/
or
http://www.domain.com/index.php?t=test%20title

I did try these options but not worked:

```
ReWriteRule ^test.php?t=(.*)$ index.php?t=$1
ReWriteRule ^test.php?t=([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?t=$1
ReWriteRule ^test\.php\?t=(.*)$ index.php?t=$1
ReWriteRule ^test\.php\?t=([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?t=$1
```

It is possible create permalink with htaccess  for this?
http://www.domain.com/t/test-title/

Answer (score 0):

Query strings are not part of match in RewriteRule directive, use %{THE_REQUEST} variable to match against query strings.

Try this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?t=([^\s]+)\s*([^\s&]+)\sHTTP/1.1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /t/%1-%2? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^t/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?t=$1%20$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am sorry for my late reply. I did try now but url changed like this: http://www.domainname.com/home/hostusername/public_html/t/test-title-HTTP/1.1    How can I do like this? http://www.domainname.com/t/test-title

Comment: @Webmaster I edited this ans, the problem was relative path in rewrite target, i have changed it to absolute path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now url changing like this : http://www.domainname.com/t/test-title-HTTP/1.1    How can remove -HTTP/1.1 from url? I need like this : http://www.domainname.com/t/test-title/

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I did try but I did get this result : 
http://www.domainname.com/t/test%2520titl-e   It's posible to like this? http://www.domainname.com/t/test-title/ and %20 can be convert to - (hyphen) character?